# How can I format a value as indian money in a textbox while typing vb.net windows application?

Tags: vb.net

How can I format a value as Indian money in a textbox while typing vb.net windows application?

for example: if `100000` is entered in the textbox I want it in this format: `1,00,000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use masked textbox and make your own mask

Have a good day

Comment: how to make mask textbox, please explain

Comment: you have to chose from ToolBox the MaskedTextBox Comp.